# Background image with a background color on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to have a background image that has a hover state of a different image **and** shows a white background.

You can see in more detail what I mean [here.](http://redsky.incredifull.com/)

The logo of CAUL/CBUA on the navigation bar is what I'm trying to fix. You can see that when you hover, it does switch to the image and also has a white background **but** the white of the background does not extend to it's full *block*. To see what I mean by *the full block*, please hover over the links right beside the logo and notice that it takes up the full block.

**EDIT**: Here is my edited CSS (only the parts that changed)

```
#navi .logo {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}

#navi .logo a {
float: left;
width: 56px;
height: 40px;
background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) center no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#navi .logo a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) center no-repeat;
background-color: white;
}
```

Here is my original CSS:

```
/* Navigation bar */
#navi {
height: 40px;
background: #1e416f;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#navi a:hover {
background: white;
color: #1e416f;
}

#navi .logo {
margin: 5px;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}

#navi .logo a {
float: left;
margin: 2px 10px;
width: 36px;
height: 26px;
background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) left top no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#navi .logo a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) left top no-repeat;
background-color: white;
}

#primary-nav, #tools-nav {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#primary-nav li, #primary-nav a, #tools-nav li, #tools-nav a {
float: left;
}

#primary-nav a, #tools-nav a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 10px;
border-right: 1px solid white;
line-height: 40px;
}

#tools-nav a:hover {
color: #1e416f;
}

#primary-nav li:first-child a, #tools-nav li:first-child a {
border-left: 1px solid white;
}

#tools-nav {
float: right;
}

#tools-nav .icon a {
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#tools-nav .email a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/mail.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .email a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_mail.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .twitter a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/twitter.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .twitter a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover-twitter.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .search a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/search.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .search a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_search.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div id="navi">
<h1 class="logo"><a href="#">CAUL/CBUA</a></h1>

<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Directories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Committees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="tools-nav">
    <li class="login"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="email icon"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li class="twitter icon"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="search icon"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `<a>` take up the whole width and height as a block.

Codepen skech: http://cdpn.io/FjJsu

**CSS**

```
#navi .logo a {
  float: left;
  width: 56px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) center no-repeat; /*Center your background*/
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

#navi .logo a:hover {
  background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) center no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swap margin with padding and reposition the background image

```
#navi .logo a {
float: left;
padding: 2px 10px;
width: 36px;
height: 26px;
background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
background-position: 50%
}
```

edit: just make sure to have the same background positioning on `:hover` as well